# Don't drag over window edges

Tags: jquery, frame, drag

I have two divs overlapping each over. 
The .second is over the .first.
Each is taking the full window in both width and height.

.second has a property of 
`position: absolute; left: -800px;`
so that you can click part of it to drag it over the .first

I'd like the drag function to prevent .second to go beyond the right edge of the frame and/or to go further than -800px left.

Comment: Can you provide your code? Are you using JQuery UI draggable widget for dragging?

Comment: In case you use jQuery UI to make the element draggable you should take a look at the parameter "containment" which allows you to set a bounding box to within dragging is limited http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

Comment: Indeed, I use jQuery API for the grabbing effect but I don't really understand the containment option. Here is a link to the workspace http://clementfauquet.com/test/port_clem/

Comment: I added a simple example on how to use jquery ui draggable with the containment option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to use the containment option of jquery ui draggable with an array. The array takes 4 numbers where the the first 2 numbers define the left-top corner of the bounding box and the last 2 numbers define the right-bottom corner of the bounding box.

So in the example below the minmum css left of the element is `0px` and the maximum css left is `400px`. The minimum css top is `10px` and the maximum css top is `200px`.

Basically you just need to adjust the values in the array to your needs.

```js
var index1 = 10;

$('#test').draggable({
  containment: [0, index1, $('body').width()/4, 200]
});

// update option containment after a window resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  $( "#test" ).draggable( "option", "containment", "parent" );
});
```

```css
body{
 height: 350px;
}

#test{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick ;) Still, as my minimum left is a negative value, I encounter issues at resize. How do I set the array with a responsive value such as `calc(100% - 100px);` ?

Comment: As you can see in the updated example you can use variables as well as expressions calculating the necessary value in the containment array. Upon a window resize you can update the containment values as shown in the example. Just use values that meet your needs. Note: The example will not update containment on SO because the iframe the code is running in does not resize.

Comment: Run the example in Full Page and the update on window resize will work as well.